# Why does JAXB suddenly barf on Java 7's new ArrayList$SubList class?

Tags: jaxb

We noticed in production at a customer site today that an `ArrayList` marshals fine under Java 6-invoked JAXB and fails under Java 7-invoked JAXB.  Specifically, a property of ours that is defined as a `List` that actually returns the result of an `ArrayList#subList(int, int)` call causes a marshaling exception when we run our code using Java 7.

This has to do with the fact that the innards of `ArrayList` have changed dramatically.  One of the things that has apparently changed is that `ArrayList#subList(int, int)` now returns a new inner class (called `SubList`).  When this class is encountered by JAXB, well, boom.  Here is a portion of the stack we're seeing:

```
Failed to create a new JAXBInstance.
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.ArrayList$SubList is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
    this problem is related to the following location:
            at java.util.ArrayList$SubList
```

Given that marshalling this used to work under Java 6, what is the suggested workaround here?

Answer (score 1):

this problem is noticed in our place, and we had to convert sublist into an AbstractPage (which is our own collection type with pagination support) collection & get serialization done.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following on JDK 1.7.0_45 for the Mac everything works for me.  Is this equivalent to what you are doing?

**Java Model**

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private ArrayList<String> bar;

    public Foo() {
        bar = new ArrayList<String>(3);
        bar.add("A");
        bar.add("B");
        bar.add("C");
        bar.add("D");

    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getBarSubset() {
        return bar.subList(1, 3);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <barSubset>B</barSubset>
    <barSubset>C</barSubset>
</foo>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. The only difference is that we're running in GlassFish.  We have not installed Moxy.  Need to check if GlassFish 3.1.2.2 is bundling its own JAXB or something else such that when run via JDK 7 it doesn't work....

Comment: @LairdNelson Based on the package `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException` the JAXB RI is being used. This is different from the repackaged version of the RI included in the JDK (which would have the package name `com.sun.internal.xml.bind`).

Comment: OK, so...hmm. Hopefully I can reproduce this in an embedded GlassFish test case.

Comment: @LairdNelson - I have emailed the JAXB RI lead about this issue.

Comment: did you ever get an answer back here?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the given test in JDK7 and in standalone latest JAXB - no failers.